# getting incorrect error even if the condition is fulfilled

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream, if-statement

I am trying to show the message based on the text shown on webpage after a particular action. If the webpage contains text **MESSAGE HAS BEEN SUBMITTED SUCCESSFULLY**, I want to print Message sent successfully on the screen otherwise MESSAGE SENDING FAILED. Everything is working fine but for one thing.

```
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sendConnection.getOutputStream()), true);
        printWriter.print(sendContent);
        printWriter.flush();
        printWriter.close();
        //Reading the returned web page to analyse whether the operation was sucessfull

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sendConnection.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder SendResult = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            SendResult.append(line);
        }

if (SendResult.toString().contains("MESSAGE HAS BEEN SUBMITTED SUCCESSFULLY")) {
            System.out.println("Message sent to " + phoneNumber + " successfully.");
        } else {
            System.err.println("Message could not send to " + phoneNumber + ". Also check login credentials");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
```

The problem is that even if the webpage contains the text **MESSAGE HAS BEEN SUBMITTED SUCCESSFULLY**, the condition always goes into `ELSE` part and show MESSAGE SENDING FAILED but thats not true because the message has been sent and i see the **MESSAGE HAS BEEN SUBMITTED SUCCESSFULLY** on the webpage.

Can anyone tell me where am i going wrong?

Comment: try printing `SendResult.toString()` and varialble name should be camlecase

Comment: and `SendResult.toString.length()` to see if there are any hidden characters.

Comment: @amit Hidden char's will not cause issue here OP is using `contains`. It will have only issue if message does not have that string

Comment: @JigarJoshi i tried that already `SendResult.toString()` and it contains the text which i have kept in the condition

Comment: @AmitD: Sure they will, if they are within the searched substring (if it is `MESSAGE HAS<HIDDEN_CHAR> BEEN....`). Or if the substring uses tabs instead of spaces, or million of other possibilities :|

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW i have not used such import

Comment: Curious if it would be simpler--and just as accurate--to search for just `SendResult.toString().contains("SUCCESSFULLY")`. Eventually it would likely be better to match against a regular expression.

Comment: @TapanDesai can you add exact output of `SendResult.toString()` in the question ?

Comment: @AmitD just now i tried `System.out.print(SendResult.toString());` but its not printing anything

Comment: @TapanDesai There is the reason :)

Comment: Are you importing SendResult?

Comment: @AmitD but why its not printing anything? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW i am not importing it. its in the same class. Its the object of `StringBuilder` as you can see here `StringBuilder SendResult = new StringBuilder();`

Comment: @TapanDesai Check if you are getting `line` really gets appended add print in the loop.

Comment: @AmitD what should i try to print in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (SendResult.toString().trim().contains("MESSAGEHASBEENSUBMITTEDSUCCESSFULLY"))
```

Comment: `trim()` does not remove whitespace from within the `String`. Only at the start and end.